# My code is bumming out before return this.each jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
( function( $ ) {              
    jQuery.support.cors = true;

    function CleanQueryString( query )
    {
        return encodeURI( query ); 
    };

    $.fn.GoogleSearchResult = function( options ) {  

        var settings = $.extend( {
            query: null,
            googleApiKey: "something",
            googleUrl: "https://www.googleapis.com/shopping/search/v1/public/",
            concatUrl: "",
            country: "UK",
            cleanQuery: ""
        }, options); 

        alert("im here"); // THIS ALERTS

        return this.each( function() {
            alert("q:" +settings.query); // THIS DOES NOT?  
            if( settings.query )
            {                                 
                alert(":" + settings.query);
                settings.cleanQuery = CleanQueryString( settings.query );
                $.ajax({       
                    dataType: "json", 
                    async: false,  
                    url: settings.googleUrl,       
                    data: {
                        key: settings.googleApiKey,
                        country: settings.country,
                        q: settings.cleanQuery,
                        alt: 'json'
                    },      
                    success: function( data ) {    
                        alert( data );
                        return data;           
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
                        alert("error " + status + " " + error); 
                    }   
                });
            }  
        } );     
    };  
} )( jQuery );
```

My code is bumming out before return this.each jquery plugin, any ideas why?

I am calling it with:

```
$.fn.GoogleSearchResult( { 
     query: "the apple ipad"
} );
```

Comment: The developer console might know. F12.

Comment: No errors? Weird stuff?

Comment: console log `this` before your loop, probably empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.each()` function iterates over the contents of the jQuery object that's it's context.  In your case, you've got no context object at all, so `.each()` will do nothing.

Given the nature of your function, I don't see why it makes sense for it to be a jQuery function at all.  You could hang it directly off the `$` object I guess, and if you do that then you don't need `.each()` at all.

Comment: boom.. thanks, left over code from when I was writing data to a div. Thanks.

Comment: I will be allowing users to return pure json, or to attach wrapper divs to the data and output to a specific DOM element. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It's the way you call it. You need to call it on a selector and not on fn.